# MySQL fulltext search does not work

Tags: php, mysql, search

I have a MySQL table structured like this:

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE test(
id INT NOT NULL,
title VARCHAR(512) NOT NULL COLLATE utf8_general_ci,
body TEXT NOT NULL COLLATE utf8_general_ci,
dateStored VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL COLLATE utf8_general_ci,
fileName VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL COLLATE utf8_general_ci,

FOREIGN KEY(id) REFERENCES `database`.`parent`(id)

);";
```

My storage engine is MYISAM.

Now, when I want to search in `body` field with the **`MATCH`** - **`AGAINST`**, there is no result…

This is my try:

```
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM database.test 
        WHERE MATCH(body) AGAINST('?')";
$prepare = $pdo->prepare($sql2);
$prepare->execute( array( $pattern ) );
$fetch = $prepare->fetchAll();
```

It seems very basic but still my code do not work. Would you tell me what is wrong with my code?

Is this because of I have a field with references to another table?

Comment: How/where is `$pattern` defined?

Comment: this is my problem too... did you test a simple query?(

Comment: I guess you dont need single quote `'?'` here

Comment: it comes from a form using ajax... I tried a simple defiend example but the problem still remains...

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty, I removed single quote but nothing changed..

Comment: first execute the query directly on mysql and see what you get.. if its not returning the data then you may need to check the ft_min_word_len and see the size if its set to 4 and you are trying with word of len 3 then it wount work. If the word occurance is more that 50% then its considered as common and it will not be returned and so on. If on mysql it works, then try executing simple query using the prepare statement and if this does not work then use error catching to see whats wrong.

Comment: Can't see the `FULLTEXT` index on `body` field. It must be there.

Comment: where is `ft_min_word_len`? is this in php.ini? I don't know what is that...!!!

Comment: @Deadooshka Would you show me please? I'm new in mysql...

Comment: @user3665682 here the syntax http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-index.html

Answer (score 5):

Add more data. By default MySQL will ignore any word that is in 50% or more of the rows in the table as it considers it would be a 'noise' word.

With very few rows in a table, it is common to hit this 50% limit often (ie. if you have two rows, every word is in at least 50% of the rows!).

Comment: You publish this answer before of mine.  This is the correct answer :)

Answer (score 3):

I think you are missing the `FULLTEXT` index on your field.  You need to [have a FULLTEXT index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html) on a column to do `MATCH AGAINST` searches.

Either declare the `FULLTEXT` index with the table or alter your current table to include the index.

```
ALTER TABLE `test` ADD FULLTEXT (`body`)
```

Also, as some others have said, there is a cut off to the word length and there is also the 50% threshold that will prevent results from showing.

Answer (score 1):

### For MySQL versions 5.6+

You just need to add a `FULLTEXT INDEX` altering the table [like Crackertastic described](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23811847/2019043) or define it directly in the `CREATE TABLE` statement.

Here is a working example:

```
-- DROP TABLE child;
-- DROP TABLE parent;

CREATE TABLE parent (
    id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB; -- or MyISAM
CREATE TABLE child(
    id INT NOT NULL,
    title VARCHAR(512) NOT NULL COLLATE utf8_general_ci,
    body TEXT NOT NULL COLLATE utf8_general_ci,
    date_stored VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL COLLATE utf8_general_ci,
    file_name VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL COLLATE utf8_general_ci,
    parent_id INT NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES parent(id),
    FULLTEXT (body)
) ENGINE=InnoDB; -- or MyISAM

INSERT INTO child (id, title, body, date_stored, file_name, parent_id) VALUES('1','test title 1','test body 1','22.05.2014','file1.txt',5);
INSERT INTO child (id, title, body, date_stored, file_name, parent_id) VALUES('2','asd','qwer','31.07.2019','yxcv.txt',6);
INSERT INTO child (id, title, body, date_stored, file_name, parent_id) VALUES('3','gfdsa','trewq','21.04.2015','hjkl.txt',7);

SELECT
    *
FROM
    child
WHERE
    MATCH(body) AGAINST('qwer')
;
```

The `SELECT` request returns the entry with the `id = 2`.

---

### For older MySQL versions

In MySQL vesions older than 5.6 was not possible to define a `FULLTEXT INDEX` on an `InnoDB` table.

From the [MySQL 5.5 docu](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html):

> Full-text indexes can be used only with `MyISAM` tables. (In MySQL 5.6 and up, they can also be used with `InnoDB` tables.)

So, one had to decide between using of `FOREIGN KEY` and `FULLTEXT INDEX` and choose the storage engine -- [`InnoDB`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-storage-engine.html) or [`MyISAM`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/myisam-storage-engine.html). Since `InnoDB` supported `FOREIGN KEY` constraints, but didn't support `FULLTEXT` indexes.

An attempt to create a `FULLTEXT INDEX` on an `InnoDB` table

```
-- DROP TABLE child;
-- DROP TABLE parent;

CREATE TABLE parent (
    id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
CREATE TABLE child(
    id INT NOT NULL,
    title VARCHAR(512) NOT NULL COLLATE utf8_general_ci,
    body TEXT NOT NULL COLLATE utf8_general_ci,
    date_stored VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL COLLATE utf8_general_ci,
    file_name VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL COLLATE utf8_general_ci,
    parent_id INT NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES parent(id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

ALTER TABLE `child` ADD FULLTEXT (`body`);
```

failed with an error:

```
Query: ALTER TABLE `child` ADD FULLTEXT (`body`)

Error Code: 1214
The used table type doesn't support FULLTEXT indexes
```

So, you had to use `MyISAM` for `FULLTEXT INDEX`. Then you just need to add a `FULLTEXT INDEX` altering the table [like Crackertastic described](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23811847/2019043) or define it directly in the `CREATE TABLE` statement.

Here is a working example:

```
-- DROP TABLE child;
-- DROP TABLE parent;

CREATE TABLE parent (
    id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
CREATE TABLE child(
    id INT NOT NULL,
    title VARCHAR(512) NOT NULL COLLATE utf8_general_ci,
    body TEXT NOT NULL COLLATE utf8_general_ci,
    date_stored VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL COLLATE utf8_general_ci,
    file_name VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL COLLATE utf8_general_ci,
    parent_id INT NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FULLTEXT (body)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;

INSERT INTO child (id, title, body, date_stored, file_name, parent_id) VALUES('1','test title 1','test body 1','22.05.2014','file1.txt',5);
INSERT INTO child (id, title, body, date_stored, file_name, parent_id) VALUES('2','asd','qwer','31.07.2019','yxcv.txt',6);
INSERT INTO child (id, title, body, date_stored, file_name, parent_id) VALUES('3','gfdsa','trewq','21.04.2015','hjkl.txt',7);

SELECT
    *
FROM
    child
WHERE
    MATCH(body) AGAINST('qwer')
;
```

The `SELECT` request returns the entry with the `id = 2`.

Comment: FYI, InnoDB supports `FULLTEXT` keys in [MySQL 5.6](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-search.html) and up.

Comment: Yes, my information was not up-to-date: "Full-text indexes can be used only with `MyISAM` tables. (In MySQL 5.6 and up, they can also be used with `InnoDB` tables.)" (from the [MySQL 5.5 docu](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html)). Thank you for updating me! It's very good news! I think, now I have to edit my answer... :)

Comment: No problem, happy to be of assistance.  I only said something because your `InnoDB` link referenced MySQL 5.6 documents, otherwise I would have left it alone.

Comment: You should NOT leave such things alone! Thank you once again and +1 for your comment. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try IN BOOLEAN MODE.  This will not ignore any rows.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-boolean.html